# Calculating the integral $\int_{0}^{\pi /6}\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{R_s\sin \theta }{C_L}\right)^2} d\theta$

Tags: integration, special-functions, definite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

I want to integrate $I=\int\limits_{0}^{\pi /6}{\sqrt{1-{{\left( \frac{{{R}_{s}}\sin \theta }{{{C}_{L}}} \right)}^{2}}}d \theta}$.
I get incomplete elliptic integral $E(z\mid m)$ in the calculation by mathematica. I need some simple calulation for including the function in further calulations along with other functions. 
Any way to proceed directly, without the help of Elliptic Integral?

Comment: Since you can't simplify, why not keep it as it is in calculations?vand evaluate in the end using elliptic integrals. Alternatively, is there any problem in evaluating to greater significant digit than needed so that later calculations do not create loss of significant digits?

Comment: Sorry I had some typo-error in equation, correted it now.

Comment: @user57 thought to do so, but was just like carry forwarding my problem to the next stage. I am doing this calculation to get of overlap between two sections and I have no idea how to interpret $E\left(\frac{\pi }{3}|\frac{R^2}{C^2}\right)$ even if it is in final result to get the exact area.

Comment: "Any way to proceed directly, without the help of Elliptic Integral?" - no, but if the goal is numerical evaluation, there are efficient methods for numerically evaluating the elliptic integral of the second kind, based on the arithmetic-geometric mean.

Comment: @J.M. As I see from reference complete elliptic integral can be computed based on the arithmetic-geometric mean efficiently, but this is an incomplete elliptic function. Can you give me some example, if possible.

Comment: First: a terminological note: elliptic integrals are **not elliptic functions**. They are inverses of elliptic functions (or at least the integral of the first kind is). Second: yes, the incomplete elliptic integral can also be computed via the AGM, but it takes more work precisely due to the incompleteness. But before all that: what are the parameter ranges for $R_S$ and $C_L$?

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for correcting me. The exact values in my calculation are $R_S =12.5$ and $C_L=19.3$.

Comment: To throw you a bone: the DLMF features [an algorithm for computing the Carlson symmetric function $R_G(x,y,z)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/19.36#ii); since there is [an identity connecting $R_G$ and $E$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/19.25.E7), you should be able to write your algorithm with that description.

Answer (score 4):

For the binomial series of $\sqrt{1-x}$ , $\sqrt{1-x}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(2n)!x^n}{4^n(n!)^2(1-2n)}$

$\therefore\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\sqrt{1-\left(\dfrac{R_s\sin\theta}{C_L}\right)^2}~d\theta=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(2n)!R_s^{2n}\sin^{2n}\theta}{4^n(n!)^2(1-2n)C_L^{2n}}d\theta=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\left(1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(2n)!R_s^{2n}\sin^{2n}\theta}{4^n(n!)^2(1-2n)C_L^{2n}}\right)d\theta$

Now for $\int\sin^{2n}\theta~d\theta$ , where $n$ is any natural number,

$\int\sin^{2n}\theta~d\theta=\dfrac{(2n)!\theta}{4^n(n!)^2}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{(2n)!((k-1)!)^2\sin^{2k-1}\theta\cos\theta}{4^{n-k+1}(n!)^2(2k-1)!}+C$

This result can be done by successive integration by parts.

$\therefore\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}}\left(1+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(2n)!R_s^{2n}\sin^{2n}\theta}{4^n(n!)^2(1-2n)C_L^{2n}}\right)d\theta$

$=\left[\theta+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{((2n)!)^2R_s^{2n}\theta}{4^{2n}(n!)^4(1-2n)C_L^{2n}}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{((2n)!)^2((k-1)!)^2R_s^{2n}\sin^{2k-1}\theta\cos\theta}{4^{2n-k+1}(n!)^4(2k-1)!(1-2n)C_L^{2n}}\right]_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}}$

$=\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{((2n)!)^2R_s^{2n}\theta}{4^{2n}(n!)^4(1-2n)C_L^{2n}}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{((2n)!)^2((k-1)!)^2R_s^{2n}\sin^{2k-1}\theta\cos\theta}{4^{2n-k+1}(n!)^4(2k-1)!(1-2n)C_L^{2n}}\right]_0^{\frac{\pi}{6}}$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{((2n)!)^2R_s^{2n}\pi}{4^{2n}6(n!)^4(1-2n)C_L^{2n}}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{((2n)!)^2((k-1)!)^2R_s^{2n}\sin^{2k-1}\dfrac{\pi}{6}\cos\dfrac{\pi}{6}}{4^{2n-k+1}(n!)^4(2k-1)!(1-2n)C_L^{2n}}$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{((2n)!)^2R_s^{2n}\pi}{2^{2n+1}3(n!)^4(1-2n)C_L^{2n}}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{((2n)!)^2((k-1)!)^2R_s^{2n}\sqrt3}{4^{2n+1}(n!)^4(2k-1)!(1-2n)C_L^{2n}}$